# How To Populate Data in Column only For First Row In Sql Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to write a query as below but it should give data populated only for the first Row in selective column. The column value in the second to last row should be blank. But the othe r column value should be present.

```
SELECT CLAIMID as "Claim Id", PAID_IN_INSTALMENTS as "Instalments", 
       F_CALCULATE_TOTAL_PAID(CLAIMID) as "Total Amount Paid"
  FROM PT_CLAIMS WHERE CLAIMID = '123456'
```

In this Query, the column "Total Amount Paid" should be populated only for the first row. Please not that i can not change the function F_CALCULATE_TOTAL_PAID. The output should be as below:

```
Claim Id   |  Instalments   |   Total Amount Paid
-----------|----------------|---------------------
123456     |   500.00       |     1800.00
-----------|----------------|---------------------
123456     |   300.00       |                     
-----------|----------------|---------------------
123456     |   600.00       |                     
-----------|----------------|---------------------
123456     |   400.00       |
```

Comment: You need to tell us what is the logic for determining what is the "first" row.  Specifically, there needs to be one (or more) columns which determine which row is logically first.

Comment: What is "selective column" and "column value in the second to last row" and "other column value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL table represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as a "first row" unless a column specifies the ordering.

Let me assume you have such a column.  In that case, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT CLAIMID as "Claim Id",
       PAID_IN_INSTALMENTS as "Instalments", 
       (CASE WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIAMID ORDER BY <ordering column>)
             THEN SUM(PAID_IN_INSTALMENTS) OVER ()
        END)  as "Total Amount Paid",
FROM PT_CLAIMS
WHERE CLAIMID = '123456'
ORDER BY <ordering column>;
```

This does not use the function `F_CALCULATE_TOTAL_PAID(CLAIMID)` because it seems to just be the total sum of `PAID_IN_INSTALMENTS` and there is a built-in function to do that.  If there is more logic in that function, you can -- of course -- use it instead of the window function:

```
       (CASE WHEN 1 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIAMID ORDER BY <ordering column>)
             THEN `F_CALCULATE_TOTAL_PAID(CLAIMID)
        END)  as "Total Amount Paid",
```